# React Image - Local Image not showing

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import bannerImage from '../img/bannerImage.jpg';

console.log(bannerImage);

const StyledBanner = styled.div`
    margin-top: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
`;

function Banner() {
    return (
        <StyledBanner>
            {/* <img src={`http://github.com/someprofile.png`} /> */}
            <img src={require("../img/bannerImage.jpg")} />
            <img src={bannerImage} />
        </StyledBanner>
    );
};

export default Banner;
```

I have this React Component that I am trying to return a local image, but this image never loads, it show the image is there but it is always broke.
I tried using require method and also the import but nothing works.

When it is an external image it works fine, only when it is local it doesnt work.

Could you please advise me how to correct this issue?

The final element that comes out of this is a DIV and those 2 images there appear as broken images, but if I change the src to a online picture it works fine.

```
<div class="sc-eDvSVe YFPxO">
<img src="[object Module]">
<img src="[object Object]">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fix is going to be to use `require("../img/bannerImage.jpg").default`, because `require` returns an object with a `default` property that you have to access.

Example from an old project of mine:

If I set my state like this:

```
setProfileImg(require("../images/" + res.data.profileImg));
```

it has the value of this object:

```
{
  "default": "/static/media/1640086164286.e03de477.png"
}
```

And so by using `.default` I access the actual image path I want.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the help!
The lines below worked pretty fine, I used console.log() to explore what came as a result of the require and import statements. There where internal properties there and I found out that I need to use as below to solve the problem.

`code`
            <img src={require("../img/bannerImage.jpg").default.src} />
            <img src={bannerImage.src} />
`code`